# What is the best unix compression utility?

Tags: unix, compression

What is the best unix compression utility available?

Comment: In terms of speed ? In terms of compression ratios ? I guess you're talking lossless (e.g. gzip etc.). I think you may need to be a little more specific.

Comment: Compression utilities also correspond to compression libraries. Removing the "not-programming-related" tag.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

depends on your speed/size tradeoff.  Gzip is fast and yields good results.  Bzip2 is slow and often yields better results.

Comment: Bzip2 file compression example: `tar -cjf file7.tar.bz2 dir/`

Answer (score 9):

A good compression utility is [7-zip](http://7-zip.org/) (p7zip on linux) using the lzma-algorithm (slow compression, good decompression speed, very good compression ratio). Can decompress most popular archive-formats.

You can also look at compression benchmark sites:

- [Maximumcompression](http://www.maximumcompression.com/)
- [Compressionratings](http://www.compressionratings.com/)

Answer (score 3):

http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8051

http://tukaani.org/lzma/benchmarks.html

Pick the best per your needs. The graphs in the first link comprehensively cover every Unix compression utility I've heard of. The second one offers some hard numbers from the more common untilities.

I tend towards lzma -2 when doing large backups, which offers smaller AND faster compression than bzip -9.

Answer (score 3):

[XZ](http://tukaani.org/xz/) compression is a relative newcomer, but is a good balance between compression and speed.  Supposedly almost as good compression as bzip2, but only slightly slower than gzip.

Answer (score 0):

bzip is pretty efficient, spacewise, but not as fast as some of the others.

From "man bzip2":

> bzip2  compresses  files  using  the Burrows-Wheeler block sorting text compression algo‐
>   rithm, and Huffman coding.   Compression  is  generally  considerably  better  than  that
>   achieved by more conventional LZ77/LZ78-based compressors, and approaches the performance
>   of the PPM family of statistical compressors.

Comment: "almost as good compression as bzip2"???  If your speaking very generally, `xz` yields higher compression ratio's than `bzip2`.